# Entity Framework LINQ query starts timing out - speeds up again after DB server reboot

Tags: linq, entity-framework, timeout

Here is an odd one.  We have a C# ASP.NET website application using EntityFramework to connect to an MS SQL Server database (SQL2010).  We recently ran into a case where a LINQ query in the app that was normally running very fast (< 2 seconds) suddenly started running so long that the connection timed-out.  There were no significant changes to the database size or the amount of data being returned from the query.  Moreover, when we ran a SQL version of the query in SQL Mgmt Studio, it ran normally (quick).

The issue was not happening in our dev or staging DBs, but when I connected to the Prod DB in Visual Studio and ran the code in debug mode, I would run into the timeout on the same query.  As a test, I made a small change to the WHERE statement that should have no impact on the query logic (ie: added a line at the end reading: '&& table.fieldname != "FOOBAR"') and then the query ran normally (fast).  When I removed the extra useless line from the WHERE statement and ran again, it was back to timing out (tried this back and forth several times).

The DBA tried doing a DROPCLEANBUFFERS on the DB and that had no effect.  In desparation, we then rebooted the production database server and this fixed the problem (query ran fast again).

I understand that EF and LINQ cache queries on the DB server.  Based on the above, it sounds to me like the cached version of this query got corrupted somehow.  I would have thought the DROPCLEANBUFFERS would have fixed it, but it appears that there is something else holding the query info that gets cleaned/reset by a reboot, but not by DROPCLEANBUFFERS.

Has anybody else ran into this issue?  Is there a way to prevent it?  Is there an easier way to flush the cached EF/LINQ queries other than rebooting?

As a side note, we had a similar problem with this same database in an earlier non-EF/non-LINQ version of the application that pulled data with regular Stored Procedures.  Every so often (2-3 times a year), one of the SPs that normally ran in a few seconds would start timingout, but only when ran from the application.  The same SP executed directly from SQL Mgmt Studio would still run normally.  The only way to fix it was to completely drop and recreate the SP.  The DBA concluded that the database was creating two execution plans for the same SP and this was the root of the issue (although we never learned exactly why it happened or how to prevent it).

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Sascoaz

Comment: Have you tried:
  1) DROP STATISTICS and then see if it's fast
  2) use (nolock), do this with IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted. 
If any of this work, it will help you to find the root cause

Comment: Are you sure you have the same indexes in all environments ?

Answer (score 0):

What else is different between your dev/staging servers vs production - is production on a VM with inadequate hardware resources perhaps?

Since this works in dev/staging, and I am assuming that your db structure is exactly the same on all 3, start looking beyond your database.

I would've just commented but I'm a noob and have no stackoverflow mojo.